# Multiplying polar complex numbers ( Check my work )

Tags: complex-numbers

I am multiplying complex numbers, but not sure if I am doing it right. Are the answers below to the questions b) and d) correct?

[image]

[image]

[image]

These answers came back as wrong. Can anyone see where i went wrong?? Thought they was correct.

Comment: Looks correct. Good job. (Perhaps you should have put * and = in answer b)

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are correct.  These problems are rather simple if you know the rule:  to multiply complex numbers in polar form, multiply the magnitudes and add the angles.

Comment: These answers came back as wrong. Can you see why?

Comment: No, I can't.  Can you check with who marked them wrong and get back to me?

Comment: Yes i will. So frustrating.